# how to embed a pdf from a url using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I've googled alot but I can't find an answer to this simple question, I just want to do something like

embed_using_pdf.js url="http://freeexampapers.com/index.php/directory/download?location=A%20Level/Accounting/Edexcel/2006%20Jan/9944774_Question%20Paper.pdf"

and I get a pdf inside my page
btw, this is a force download link, that's why I don't want to use an iframe or an object.

Comment: [PDF.js Can I load a PDF from another server](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-i-load-a-pdf-from-another-server-cross-domain-request)